# How to show that set of strings of odd length in $\{a,b,c\}^*$ is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Through diagonalization method, can I show that set of strings of odd length in $\{a,b,c\}^*$ is countable?

Comment: You can use that a countable union of countable set is countable

Comment: Diagonalization is typically used to show something *isn't* countable. For this problem, use the fact that "the union of countably many finite sets is also countable".

Comment: Thanks Henry, but in that case, how I could use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_{2n+1}$ denote the set of string of length exactly $2n+1$. Since this set is finite, there is a mapping $f_n:S_{2n+1} \to |S_{2n+1}|$ (where |S| denotes the cardinality of $S$)which lists all elements in $S_{2n+1}$. Now consider the function $f:\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}S_{2n+1} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by 
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\nu-1}|S_{2k+1}|+f_{\nu}(x),$$
where $\nu$ is such that $x$ has length $2\nu+1$. Now let $x,y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$, there exists $\nu_x,\nu_y$ such that $x \in S_{2\nu_x+1},y \in S_{2\nu_y+1}$. If $\nu_x < \nu_y$ then 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\nu_x-1}|S_{2k+1}| <\sum_{k=0}^{\nu_y-1}|S_{2k+1}|,$$
and since $f_{\nu_x}(z)\leq |S_{2\nu_x+1}|$ for every $z\in S_{2\nu_x+1}$ we must have $f(x)<f(y)$ which is a contradiction. If $\nu_x = \nu_y$ then $f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $f_{\nu_x}(x)=f_{\nu_x}(y)$ and since $f_{\nu_x}$ is a bijection, we must have $x=y$. This shows that $f$ is injective. Now let $m \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $\nu$ be such that
$$\tilde m :=\sum_{k=0}^{\nu}|S_{2k+1}| < m\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\nu+1}|S_{2k+1}|,$$
then we must have $1\leq m-\tilde m \leq |S_{2\nu+1}|$ and since $f_\nu:S_{2\nu+1}\to |S_{2\nu+1}|$ is a bijection, there exists some $x \in S_{2\nu+1}$ such that $f_\nu(x)=m-\tilde m$. We finally get $f(x) = \tilde m + m-\tilde m = m$, which shows that $f$ is surjective. Thus $f$ is bijective and $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}S_{2n+1} $ is countable.

Comment: Thanks Surb, but there isn't something of more simple? My teacher has not explained that.

Comment: @miclen Not to my knowledge. However, the idea is very simple (somehow you classify the words by increasing lengths and you count) but rigor is a little bit more nasty :).

Comment: @miclen note that you can always argue as commented in the OP: the set of odd length string is a countable union of finite set and thus countable (and then your refer to someone who already did the work :) for union of any countable finite set). Which is an accepted fact usually (depends on your background) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set#Formal_definition_and_properties

Comment: I have read on book "Introduction to the Theory of Computation (Michael Sipser)" that it was possible also through characteristic sequence, namely it is similar at proof who some languages are not Turing-recognizable.

Comment: As soon as possible, I'll ask that problem to my teacher, meantime your answer and help are exhaustive

Comment: @miclen Let us know if you can get a better solution :).

Comment: Surely, thank you very much :D